# Как производить "быстрый поиск" в базе?

Tags: sql, postgresql, поиск, поисковая-оптимизация, postgresql9.6

На сайте есть несколько разделов, в этих разделах отображаются таблицы с данными. Например таблица пользователей и их информация.

Есть одно единственное поле поиска, в которое "искатель" может написать любой текст, например "ива" и в итоге в таблице должны отобразиться только те строки, где присутствует данная строка. Столбцов может быть много, хоть 50, поиск может быть осуществлён и по числу (ну например "количество подчинённых у пользователя"), а также таблицы могут быть связанными (например с таблицей адресов пользователей, настроек, подразделения и т.д.).

Вопрос: каким способом это осуществлять?

1. Считаю, что способ поиска строки через `LIKE %searchString%` по всем столбцам крайне неэффективна, поэтому этот вариант сразу не рассматриваю.
2. Был вариант делать конкатенацию значений всех (или почти всех) столбцов и только по сконкатенированной строке делать `LIKE %searchString%`. На сколько это эффективно?
3. Был вариант выгрузить данные на клиент, но там хранить негде такой объём данных. `localStorage` слишком маленький.
4. Может быть использовать какие-то кэширующие средства? Какие?
5. Может быть использовать какие-то специализированные поисковые движки? Какие? Получается надо будет дублировать информацию из основной базы в движковою?

В общем, как это правильно делать? Что применять? На что обращать внимание? Какие нюансы и т.д.

Comment: Почему вопрос пытаются закрыть? Поясните. Это важный вопрос для работы с быстрым поиском на любом сайте и вопрос оптимизации и алгоритма поиска

Comment: [Полнотекстовый поиск](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev по всей-то таблице и всем столбцам? Не умрёт ли база с сотнями тысяч записей в таблице? Да и `to_tsvector` обрезает слова до корня, чтобы искать без учёта окончаний, что уже не является корректным. А с если искать еще и по номерам - тем более не будет работать.  А если учесть то, что есть связанные таблицы, и не одна, что-то сомнительно 
 такое решение. Плюс `tsvector` - столбец для таблицы. А со связанными таблицами что делать?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev в общем ваша ссылка решает проблему поиска по некоторой определённой кучке столбцов и для определённых случаев по ранжированию этих результатов. Для поиска, описанного в вопросе он не подходит.

Comment: Тогда Elasticsearch. Если и он вам не подходит, то придётся писать свой движок полнотекстового поиска, так как ничего лучше в мире нет.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev так может быть напишите ответ с подробными разъяснениями?) Потому что для вас что-то очевидное, для других (например для меня) в данном вопросе абсолютная тьма. Собственно поэтому и вопрос